# Why do irregular verb lists not show present tense changes?

Tags: conjugation, irregular-verb

In most lists of irregular verbs, in particular the list in my Langenscheidt's dictionary, the list contains the infinitive, the past tense, and the past participle forms to show the irregularity. However it doesn't list the irregularity in the conjugation in the present tense (for example for *lesen* there is no indication that the stem changes to *lies* in the second and third person singular). And the irregular conjugations aren't listed in the entry for the word (such as *lesen)* or as separate entries *(liest).*

Is there some way that I should be able to know the present tense changes from the past and past participle changes? Or do I need to rely on a different source to learn the present tense conjugations of irregular verbs?

Comment: If you can't find a dictionary that lists those changes: The vowel change in the present tense for strong verbs is somewhat regular, at least it has certain [patterns](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=29).

Answer (score 2):

Probably an older edition. Normally lists of irregular verbs are not the state-of-art. And  in older editions such lists were meant mainly for Germans. Gradually publishing houses have discovered that there are people who want to learn German and that dictionaries for learners require a totally new concept.

Have a look at recent editions of dictionaries, Langenscheidt or Pons, and you will see the difference.